# Do any other Origin games ignore reconfiguring WIndows to put the Documents folder elsewhere?

Tags: origin, windows

Note, this topic was made from reconfiguring the default save location in the Documents library of Windows 7.  Not from moving the Documents folder from within the properties window.

I reconfigured Windows to have my Documents folder on my giant D: drive HDD instead of my C: drive SSD, but I noticed The Sims 3 still put its data in the old location.

I have learned about symbolic links from another question on here that should solve the problem for The Sims 3, but if other Origin games have the same problem of ignoring the new Documents location configuration I'll want to set up the symbolic links differently. If they do, can I just make a symbolic link for both the entire Electronic Arts and EA Games folders, and not have to worry about them putting data on my C: drive again?

This question is not about The Sims 3 itself and I have already found out how to solve The Sims 3 issue.  This question is about if **other** Origin games will have the same problem — I simply want to know if other games will give the same problem so I don't have to do the symbolic link thing more than twice.

The guide I used to reconfigure the my documents location is here for anyone who needs it.
http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-performance/move-the-my-documents-folder-to-another-drive/a41eaabb-2c5b-4502-85ba-fd49a007fd82

Comment: Moving your Documents folder without changing it in Windows is a fantastic way to break a ton of functionality.

Comment: I did change it in windows.  That's not the issue here.
I created a new documents folder, went into the documents library, and changed the default save location to the new documents folder on the larger hard drive following a guide.

Comment: @Sales_Kital Posting a link to the guide you used may help others figure out what's wrong.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie
I used the guide someone made here.  It seems to work so far for steam, Sims 3 was the first one that it didn't work for.  I don't know if other Origin games have the same problem.
http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-performance/move-the-my-documents-folder-to-another-drive/a41eaabb-2c5b-4502-85ba-fd49a007fd82

Comment: Any particularly reason you wouldn't just create a directory junction?

Comment: What's a directory junction?  Also, does that make it so the C drive will never get any data on it from my documents?

Comment: [Directory junctions vs symbolic and hard links](http://devtidbits.com/2009/09/07/windows-file-junctions-symbolic-links-and-hard-links/). Yeah, it makes it so that the C: drive won't get any Documents data. It will show in C:, but it actually exists and takes up space on D:.

Comment: weird. the directory junction mentioned in that link looks like the thing I found out about that someone called a symbolic link in another question.
This is where I mean http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/34702/how-do-i-change-my-sims-3-installed-content-and-saved-games-location

Comment: They use the same command, just different options of it. A junction is more 'hidden' from other programs than a symlink is.

Comment: so, how would I set up a directory junction from the old my documents folder to the D drive?  just replace what is listed in the other question with a /j instead of a /d?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out Steam also ignores the library modifications.  To redirect steam and origin easily to another drive, go to your "my documents" folder. Right click, go to properties, from there click on Location, click "move..." then using the window that comes up, just choose where "My Documents" will be moved to.  This process I have already tested and it works with Steam cloud synch.  This method is much simpler than a Directory Junction and already built in to Windows 7.